# Null pointer exception when I try to build liferay services using servicebuilder

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-6

I have a "ECLocalDataService.java" class. I am trying to build it as liferay local service, so that I can access it from all portlets and velocity templates using ServiceLocator.findService().

My ECLocalDataService is somewhat like this:

```
public interface ECDataLocalService {

    public java.lang.String getBeanIdentifier();


    public void setBeanIdentifier(java.lang.String beanIdentifier);

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
    public float getPriceBySKU(java.lang.String sku);
}
```

and its implementation class is like this:

```
import com.rosettastone.service.base.ECDataLocalServiceBaseImpl;

public class ECDataLocalServiceImpl extends ECDataLocalServiceBaseImpl {

    public float getPriceBySKU(String sku) {
        float price = 125.99f; 
        return price;
    }

}
```

I have registered my ECDataLocalService in my service.xml

```
<service-builder package-path="com.rosettastone">
    <author>rajeshp</author>
    <namespace>mycompany</namespace>

    <entity name="ECDataLocalService" local-service="true" remote-service="false" human-name="ECDataLocalService"></entity>

</service-builder>
```

Now after this, when I click the "BuildServices" icon in Liferay Dev Studio, it throws NullPointer exception. It doesn't even show for what object that it found a NullPointer for, no error message or log messages, just simply display NullPointerException and the service doesn't get built.

Comment: Can you run this in the debugger?

Comment: Your entity has no columns, and no primary key columns. After you have added these, I'd recommend that you run this from the command line as ant-task: ant build-service. Then go thru the stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<entity name="ECDataLocalService" local-service="true" remote-service="false" human-name="ECDataLocalService"></entity>
```

At this time, there's only one <entity> element in your code sample. It has no columns, and no primary key columns defined. Code generation cannot possibly work under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

build-services ant task is meant for building a service from a service.xml that defines a table or tables. It then generates all Java code for you. There's no need to create Java files first, in fact I don't think that will work.

I would read this Liferay wiki article, and that should get you on your way.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Service+Builder

Once you have your resulting service jar from this put that on your tomcat classpath so other portlets can access the service.